# CSS class getting completely ignored

Tags: html, css, css-specificity, bulletedlist

I'm trying to do something that seems really simple but is turning out to be a pain. I have to style the bullets on a ul to be a different color than the text. After trying the pseudo class method (:before) and getting nothing but headaches I decided to use a span tag as that seems like a very simple solution. The problem I'm having now is that it seems no matter what I do the class is getting completely ignored, even when I inspect in dev tools it shows nothing in the "styles" panel. Here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-color-a">
 <li><span>Blah blah blah blah</span></li>
 <li><span>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list-color-a {
  color: orange;
  margin-left: -1.35em; 
}
.list-color-a span {
  color: gray;
}
```

Wish I had more info to offer on this but if anyone can give any inspired suggestions as to what could be happening here it'd be much appreciated (could be a specificity issue but if that were the case wouldn't dev tools still show the declarations and just have them crossed out?).

Comment: works fine here,: [http://jsfiddle.net/tbfa8kyf/](http://jsfiddle.net/tbfa8kyf/) You have a random `</strong>` in there but that shouldn't do anything to effect the css

Comment: if the above jsfiddle is working, there may be other css conflicting.  Did you try adding !important to your class attributes?

Comment: @tganyan do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Sadly no, building out a few pages for a well known tech company so because of security I can't share any links. I'm starting to suspect there's something very specific to this site that may be causing this since it's very simple code that seems to be working in all other environments; I'll post back here if/when I find out what the cause is.

Comment: Try checking the developer tools under the "computed styles" section to see what styles are being used for your `<li>` and your `<span>`

Comment: @tganyan are you perhaps overriding this style somewhere else? remember the order of precedence, style attribute (inline) > style tag > external css

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has been solved by now, but I have come across the same issue and torn out my hair eventually realising that the browser has been caching the old CSS file before I added the new class. Try reloading the page with a cache clear (CTRL-F5).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your code snippet works just fine?

```css
.list-color-a {
  color: orange;
  margin-left: -1.35em; 
}
.list-color-a span {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-color-a">
 <li><span>Blah blah blah blah</span></li>
 <li><span>Blah blah blah blah blah blah</span></li>
</ul>
```